# std::conditional with SFINAE

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, sfinae, enable-if

Is it possible to create a sort of std::enable_if_and_else, like std::conditional but without the compile time errors for classes that are not defined.

Here is an example:

```
static constexpr bool myExpr = true;

struct A {};
struct B;

struct C :
    std::conditional<myExpr,
      A,
      B>::type
    {};  // Compilation error: B is declared but not defined

struct D :
    enable_if_else<myExpr,
      A,
      B>::type
    {};  // It works
```

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't `myExpr`  be `true` so it takes the `A` branch?

Comment: yes, wrong copy and paste. You're right. Thanks

Comment: In any case, [I cannot reproduce the error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ce6197045347aed). What compiler are you using?

Comment: you're right, the code I was working with is different. I've tried to make a base case but it seems different.. I'll check it again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a sort of std::enable_if_and_else, like std::conditional but without the compile time errors for classes that are not defined.

There shouldn't any errors for `std::conditional<true, A, B>::type` if `B` is incomplete, because you're not using `B` in a way that requires it to be complete.

So `std::conditional` is already what you're looking for.

Comment: yes, you're right. The code I was working with is different, I just tried to reduce it to a base case, but there's some difference. I'll edit the question. Thanks to pointing this out

Comment: ok I've found what was the problem in my code. I've tested std::conditional in many ways and you're totally right. Thank you again