# Alternative to std::conditional_t which do not evaluate both types

Tags: c++

The need for `std::conditional_t` of evaluating both of 2 types, is quite annoying.

I am trying to get over it.

I come with a lot of solutions below, but I want to ask if there is a more readable approach.

The requirement exists because a "handler" class (e.g. a view) must provide some types, based on if "handled" class (e.g. viewed) has that functionality or not.
E.g. a matrix with accessed rows/columns/diagonal/distinct elements, provide not all of these functionalities and a view to that matrix.

My 3 solutions following below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
concept IsAccepted = requires() { typename T::Type; };

struct A { typedef std::vector<double> Type; };
struct B { typedef bool                Type; };
struct C {};
typedef int D;

template<typename T>
struct View1
{
    // T::Type must be evaluated and this is a big problem
    typedef std::conditional_t<IsAccepted<T>, typename T::Type, void> Type;
};

template<typename T>
struct View2
{
    struct Dumb { typedef void Type; };
    typedef typename std::conditional_t<IsAccepted<T>, T, Dumb>::Type Type;
};

template<typename T>
struct View3
{
    template<typename S> requires( IsAccepted<S>) static constexpr typename S::Type get();
    template<typename S> requires(!IsAccepted<S>) static constexpr void             get();

    typedef decltype(get<T>()) Type;
};

template<typename T>
struct View4
{
    static constexpr auto get()
    {
        if constexpr (IsAccepted<T>) return (typename T::Type*) {};
        else return (void*) {};
    }

    typedef std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(get())> Type;
};


int main()
{
    View1<A> a1;   View1<A>::Type a1t{};
    View1<B> b1;   View1<B>::Type b1t{};
    //View1<C> c1;  // Unacceptable! C::Type is not exist but it is evaluated
    //View1<D> d1;  // Unacceptable! int::Type is not exist but it is evaluated

    View2<A> a2;   View2<A>::Type a2t{};
    View2<B> b2;   View2<B>::Type b2t{};
    View2<C> c2; //View2<C>::Type c2t{};    //because of void
    View2<D> d2; //View2<D>::Type d2t{};    //because of void

    View3<A> a3;   View3<A>::Type a3t{};
    View3<B> b3;   View3<B>::Type b3t{};
    View3<C> c3; //View3<C>::Type c3t{};    //because of void
    View3<D> d3; //View3<D>::Type d3t{};    //because of void


    View4<A> a4;   View4<A>::Type a4t{};
    View4<B> b4;   View4<B>::Type b4t{};
    View4<C> c4; //View4<C>::Type c4t{};    //because of void
    View4<D> d4; //View4<D>::Type d4t{};    //because of void
}
```

PS: It seems opinion based question, but please leave it because it provides alternatives to another people.

Comment: Don't invent a bicycle: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html#mp_eval_if_cc_t_f_u

Comment: `Dumb` can be replaced by [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity).

Comment: the line between opinion based and not opinion bases is thin. Often its just a matter of rephrasing the question. This could go as a self answered question: "How to do it?" and the solutions posted as answer. Though, I remember a duplicate on this...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43250849/4117728

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62746757/4117728

Comment: Once you spell an expression, if it is not instantiable as a type, compilation fails, unless guarded by `if constexpr`, in which case the type is best spelled in a lambda with too much syntactic noise. If you want this, I can write it; but you'd need to hide the syntactic noise behind a macro by your own.

Answer (score 6):

```
template<bool, template<class...>class, class, class Else=void>
struct apply_if {
  using type=Else;
};

template<template<class...>class Z, class X, class Else>
struct apply_if<true,Z,X,Else> {
  using type=Z<X>;
};

template<bool test, template<class...>class Z, class X, class Else=void>
using apply_if_t=typename apply_if<test,Z,X,Else>::type;
```

This is a primitive to help out.

```
template<class X>
using type_t=X::type;
```

(Please use lower case `type` to maintain compatibility with std template metafunctions.)

Now your code is just:

```
using type=apply_if_t<IsAccepted<T>, type_t, T>;
```

which is pretty clear at point of use.

There are going to be many ways to do this in general.  This is an attempt to do so given the limitations, conventions and syntax of the C++ template metaprogramming language.

The result is that `apply_if_t` is both semantically and syntactically simple; so you can both clearly document what it means, and intermediately skilled C++ programmers can understand and verify its implementation.

Code not compiled; apologies for typos.  I am certain technique is valid.

Answer (score 2):

Yakk's answer gives a way to make an alternative type without full evaluation. However, if you would prefer to completely get rid of `View::Type` when a condition is not satisfied, you can achieve that through template specialisation, like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct ViewType {};

template<typename T>
requires(IsAccepted<T>)
struct ViewType<T> {
    typedef T::Type Type;
};
```

If there are multiple, possibly independent features that you want to check, then of course you don't want to spell out every possible combination. However, you can use the above pattern separately for each feature, and then combine them all through inheritance. For example:

```
template<typename T>
struct ViewType {};

template<typename T>
requires(IsAccepted<T>)
struct ViewType<T> {
    typedef T::Type Type;
};

template<typename T>
struct ViewElement {};

template<typename T>
requires(IsAccepted<T> && requires{ typename T::Type::value_type; })
struct ViewElement<T> {
    typedef T::Type::value_type Element;
};


template<typename T>
struct View1 : public ViewType<T>, public ViewElement<T> {};

int main()
{
    View1<A> a1;   View1<A>::Type a1t{}; View1<A>::Element a1e{};
    View1<B> b1;   View1<B>::Type b1t{};
    View1<C> c1;  
    View1<D> d1;  
}
```